# XML parsing in java : ignore tags as value

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I am having some troubles with parsing an XML file.

**The Problem:**

```
<verification appearance="4">
       content="<myTag>test<myTag>/images/titleIcon.png"  
</verification>
```

For parsing I used the following:

```
DocumentBuilder db;
db = DocumentBuilderfactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
this.doc = db.parse()
```

If I access the content with `[...]getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent()`,
it returns the value without the tags.

I assume the problem has something to do with `db.parse()`.  More Specifically, that he parses `&lt;myTag>` as a node or something like that.

How can I get the full TextContent as String (including Tags etc.)?

Is there a way to tell the parser (if that's the problem) to ignore all Content that is within two tags?

I already googled a lot. But Solutions like using &lt ; for <  isn't that what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

To do this this XML would have to be like this:

```
<verification appearance="4">
<![CDATA[
       content="<myTag>test<myTag>/images/titleIcon.png"  
]]>
</verification>
```

Then the parser will work as you want it to work.

Comment: Will you ask another question of how to make CDATA ignore "]]>"?

Comment: Oh.. I missed that possibility. Well at first i will try to fix this by my own. But solutions are welcome.

Comment: Not following, is there another issue?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. An example:
<verification appearance="4">
<![CDATA[
     content="<myTag>test<myTag>/images/titleIcon.png ]]>"  
]]>
</verification>
This testcase results in a parsing error, since there two times ]]>
I think a way to solve this is a global dtd definition at the start of the xml file.. but i'm very new to this and have to figure out how this works at first. Maybe someone with more experience in xml has a solution.

Comment: yay, why would you have this markup inside of the CDATA section? Maybe you should not be using XML at all for this.